# How to use ADFS Authentication in Windows 8.1 Store app?

Tags: windows-8.1, adfs, windows-rt, adfs2.1

Is there any samples on how to use ADFS Authentication in Win 8.1 Store apps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633593.aspx help?

You might also consider following http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog for more details.